# URL scheme to open Watch app for pairing Apple Watch

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift

Is there any URL scheme, so I can open "Watch" app on button click, to pair Apple watch ? like:

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(string : /* Watch URL Scheme? */)
```

Or is there any other way to open the "Watch" app on a button click?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The watch URL scheme is `itms-watch://`

Comment: `itms-watchs://` worked for me

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple schemes listed in the below link.

https://medium.com/@contact.jmeyers/complete-list-of-ios-url-schemes-for-apple-apps-and-services-always-updated-800c64f450f

'itms-watchs://bridge:root=GENERAL_LINK' worked for me